# Binary fast exponentiation method

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Evaluate $17^{93} \mod 23$

\begin{align}e &= 93\\
&= 1 × 2^6 + 0 × 2^5  + 1 × 2^4+ 1 × 2^3 + 1 × 2^2  + 0 × 2^1 + 1 × 2^0\\
&= |\ 1011101\ |_2
\end{align}
Then we have:
\begin{align}17^{93} \mod 23 &= (((((((17^1 )^2 17^0 )^2 17^1 )^2 17^1 )^2 17^1 )^2 17^0 )^2 17^1\\
&= (((17^4 17)^2 17)^2 17)^4 17 \text{ $\leftarrow$ step 3}\\
&= 21
\end{align}

How do we go from step 3 to final answer? What are the theorems used?

Comment: Here is your answer. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31561/30150

Comment: I don't understand the pseduo-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *just* a modular multiplication : 
\begin{align}17^{93} \mod 23 &= (((((((17^1 )^2 17^0 )^2 17^1 )^2 17^1 )^2 17^1 )^2 17^0 )^2 17^1\\
&= (((((17^2)^2 17)^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17 \text{ $\leftarrow$ step 3}\\
&= (((((289 \bmod\ 23)^2 17)^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= ((((13^2 17)^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= (((((169 \bmod\ 23) 17)^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= ((((8 \times 17)^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= ((((136 \bmod 23)^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= (((21^2 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= ((((441\ \bmod\ 23) 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= (((4 \times 17)^2 17)^2)^2 17\\
&= etc..\\
&= 21
\end{align}

Comment: `17^93 = 17^5 x (17^22)^4` then `(17^22)^4 mod(23) = 1` (Fermat's theorem)   then `17^5 mod 23 = 21`

Comment: @user11 yes, but when you use an algorithm to compute the answer, you cannot use the Fermat theorem in such a way.

Comment: You mean the method will no longer be  fast exponentiation method?

Comment: @user11 exactly.

Comment: Alright. Applying fermat's theorem seems to be fast in this problem?

Comment: Using the Fermat's theorem is a (elegant) solution to solve the initial question. But it will not be a *binary fast exponentiation* which has been described [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31559/modular-exponentiation-on-calculator-for-textbook-rsa/31561#31561). You said you didn't understand the step3. I *just* unrolled the algorithm given above. I solved it the same way a computer would have, not as a mathematician.